# Why does mariaDB wrongfully ask for missing component

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mariadb

I'm trying to build from source MariaDB on CentOS 7.  I have only done the following commands before I get the error shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pguX1.gif):

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ wget https://downloads.mariadb.org/interstitial/mariadb-5.5.40/source/mariadb-5.5.40.tar.gz/from/http%3A//ftp.ddg.lth.se/mariadb
$ tar xzvf mariadb
$ cd mariadb-5.5.40/
$ chown -R root.root .
$ cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local/mariadb
```

[proof that libaio-devel is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8pub.png)

Comment: Seems like the problem and solution are pretty clearly spelled out in the error message.

Comment: Trust me, I have installed the required package `yum install libaio-devel` I even did it the second time, and I got error, saying libaio is already installed.

Comment: this is a very specialized question, Try to report the bug to MariaDb : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/development/debugging-mariadb/reporting-bugs/

Comment: Also see how to debug a build: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/development/debugging-mariadb/reporting-bugs/#example-of-doing-a-debug-build

Comment: @ElzoValugi I probably will, I just wanted to know if this error is from my part.

Comment: @ElzoValugi Hmm, now I get `Perl is required to build MySQL using the configure to CMake translator.
`

Comment: I hope it works now, still you can report that the message that they give is not helpful

Comment: @ElzoValugi Yea, I will. Have you built it from source before? If so, what instructions did work out for you

Comment: No I haven't. I did not need to on my platform. sorry

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that is in a similar situation, cmake apparently does a pretty bad job of re-checking dependencies, even removing the cache file doesn't work very well.

Just delete and re-extract from the .tar.gz and then cmake again, if you actually have the dependencies then they will be found.